# Is there any bootstrap property like CSS clear?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="temp-box" >
            <img id="weather-icon" src='Icons/sunny.png'></img>
            <span id="temperature">50F</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" >  <div class="text-center" id="coodrs-title" ><span>Current Location</span></div>
            <div class="position">
            You Current Latitude Is: <span id="lati"></span><br/>
            You Current Longitude Is: <span id="lngi"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and i want the img with id #weather-icon be placed above the  element with id #temperature, but both of them be inside the same row. How can i do this?

Ankit Agarwal gave me the best solution. Boootstrap's clear class!!!

Comment: why cant you change the order in HTML itself?

Comment: If you could make a jsfiddle, it would be easier to 'fiddle' with :)

Comment: Yes you can do this by using bootstrap `clear` class. See my answer

Comment: I would at least try setting display:block, as I mentioned below. It might be easier & cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution is to use `.clear` bootstrap class. It willl work perfectly

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="temp-box" >
            
            <img id="weather-icon" src='Icons/sunny.png'></img>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <span id="temperature">50F</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" >  <div class="text-center" id="coodrs-title" ><span>Current Location</span></div>
            <div class="position">
            You Current Latitude Is: <span id="lati"></span><br/>
            You Current Longitude Is: <span id="lngi"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have a 'clear' class, it has a 'clearfix' class.

Comment: I don't think this works because of the "clear" class.  It works with any div because it's adding a block-level element between the two inline elements.

Comment: Yes, i mistakenly said that this a bootstrap class. It is not. But yes it creates a block level entity which shifts the next element to the next line

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that any ol' `<div>` will do, but it's cleaner to style the current elements instead of adding new empty ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest rows, like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="temp-box">
        <div class="row">
            <img id="weather-icon" src=''>IMAGE</img>
        </div>
        <div class="row"><span id="temperature">50F</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is the *best* way to to this, but it works.

Comment: Looks like I misread the question. Whoops! Doesn't matter though, as I'm sure the other answers are better

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
#weather-icon {
  display: block;
}
```

Currently you have an img & a span next to each other, which are both creating inline boxes.  One way to force your image to have a line of its own is to set it to a block box element. At least that's my understanding of how it works.

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjzBRv

Answer (score 0):

View code:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" id="temp-box" >
  <img id="weather-icon" src='Icons/sunny.png'></img><br>
 <span id="temperature">50F</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" >
 <div class="text-center" id="coodrs-title" ><span>Current Location</span></div> <div class="position"> You Current Latitude Is: <span id="lati"></span><br/> You Current Longitude Is: <span id="lngi">
  </span> 
 </div> 
 </div> 
 </div>
```

In the code next "img" there is "br".

Comment: <br> are not usually considered the best because they are not semantic. I believe they can make it harder to style the code with CSS as well, but I'm not certain.